# Interesting libraries based on LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

Every man and his dog seems to be adding an implementation of LINQ to something.

- http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/
- [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/aconrad/linq-to-rest)
- http://linqtowikipedia.codeplex.com/
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx
- http://mhinze.com/linq-to-nhibernate-in-10-minutes/

it's even been ported to javascript http://jslinq.codeplex.com/

But I'm wondering about other more niche LINQ to projects or implementation that are out there that we should know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx), which uses LINQ to define and manipulate asynchronous processing workflows as if they were observable collections.

Answer (score 3):

Linq to Lucene. Lucene is the open source Java Full Text Search (Ported to .Net called Lucene.NET) library and has its own querying syntax. Perfect fit for Linq.

http://linqtolucene.codeplex.com/